# What time of day does Microsoft Release patches on "Patch Tuesday"

Tags: security, windows-update, patch-management

I've tried my servers and they don't see the patches that Microsoft has released. Usually Windows Update automatically installs them on Wednesday, so it must be something late in the day -- yet I can't find this info anywhere on either the Wikipedia page or on Microsoft's site for Patch Tuesday. Anyone have authoritative source for the time of day they are released?

The wiki [discussion page for Patch Tuesday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Patch_Tuesday) laments this as well:

> "What time exactly are the updates released? I never seem to notice them till wednesday, and I see nothing as of yet (14:03 UTC) today. --Zilog Jones 13:03, 11 July 2006 (UTC)")

Comment: Counts the seconds for you: https://m417z.com/ms-patch-tuesday/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/security/msrc/whatwedo/updatecycle.aspx), they release them at approximately 10 AM Pacific time.

Comment: That would be 1800 UTC during winter and 1700 UTC during daylight savings time in the pacific zone.

My experience is that it's usually a bit later than that; I normally see them about 1930-2000 UK time (ie 1130-1200 Pacific Time).

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is no scheduled time. If you are worried about missing them, Microsoft does have various security advisory notifcation methods available:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd252948.aspx

Comment: I'm not worried about missing them; I want to do the patch deployment by hand in a certain sequence and without knowing when they will be released, I have to delay it a day (til tomorrow off-hours).

Answer (score 0):

It's usually before 11:00 PST/PDT, but I've seen them released as late as 15:00 MST.

Comment: Microsoft Standard Time?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to determine when packages are installed in on a domain, look at WSUS and control it from the server level.